# How to create a URL that when clicked approves or adds a name to a list within firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, url, firebase

Within firebase, I'd like to create a URL that when clicked will add someone's name to a list within firebase data structure. If that's not possible, have URLs that when clicked on marks that person as approved within firebase.

For example, consider the following structure:

```
-Sample (which would be at https://Sample.firebaseio.com)
     -Users
```

I want to produce the following

```
-Sample (which would be at https://Sample.firebaseio.com)
     -Users
         Liz_Smith
         Shanna_Oreily
```

By creating a URL like this:

```
https://Sample.firebaseapp.com/users/Liz_Smith
https://Sample.firebaseapp.com/users/Shanna_Oreily
```

I don't think something like this is possible, because it's as if pushing with a URL. If it's not possible, I'd like to have the following URLs active, meaning that they actually exist as URLs

```
https://Sample.firebaseapp.com/users/Liz_Smith
https://Sample.firebaseapp.com/users/Shanna_Oreily
```

And when the someone goes to that URL, that the person is updated as approved, which would turn this:

```
-Sample (which would be at https://Sample.firebaseio.com)
     -Users
         Liz_Smith
              approved: False
         Shanna_Oreily
              approved: False
```

into something like this:

```
-Sample (which would be at https://Sample.firebaseio.com)
     -Users
         Liz_Smith
              approved: True
         Shanna_Oreily
              approved: True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't think something like this is possible, because it's as if pushing with a URL.

You can store a URL within Firebase.

For this circumstance you can add an event listener for an anchor tag. When it is clicked you can set the data to Firebase. If you also attach a listener for the users location in Firebase you can append those links to the page in realtime.

Below is an example done with jQuery, but it can easily be adapted to which ever process or framework you use.

**[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3XQ33xoQyFBqgPuXRkBm?p=preview)**

```
  var fbRef = new Firebase('https://firenode.firebaseio.com/'),
    userRef = fbRef.child('users'),
    appUrlBase = 'https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/',
    links = $('#people-list > li a'),
    urlList = $('#url-list');

  // create click handlers for every link
  $.each(links, function(key, link) {

    var $link = $(link),
        name = $link.text(),
        url = appUrlBase + name;

    $link.on('click', function(e) {
      userRef.child(name).set({
        approvedUrl: url // <- this is a URL
      });
    });

  });

  // helper function for creating lis with a tags
  function createLi(url) {
    var li = $('<li></li>');
    li.append('<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>');
    return li;
  }

  // listen for the additions to the users location
  // when items are added we can append to the list
  userRef.on('child_added', function(snap) {
    var url = snap.val().approvedUrl;
      elem = createLi(url);

    urlList.append(elem);
  });
```